# Word to Describe the Property of a Notebook Binder

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word that describes the following idea:

> This binder is a spiral binder that has the ability to be opened and allows one to change, add or remove sheets from the notebook.

Thus far, my best idea is "expandable spiral-binder", but it feels inaccurate and incomplete.

Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I found your title a little confusing because according to your post, you're actually asking for a way to describe an expandable spiral notebook...or it is a binder?  If it's a spiral-bound binder, how can sheets be added to it?  How would you hole-punch a sheet that would work with a spiral-bound binder?  If it's a notebook that's pre-loaded with blank paper, like other spiral-bound notebooks, you'd rip out the pages or perhaps they're scored for neat removal but how would it be expandable?

Comment: I suspect that you mean a ring binder. As @KristinaLopez says above, a spiral bound notebook does not normally allow pages to be added (because the spiral cannot be opened, except by completely removing it.)

Comment: Yes, I probably mean a ring binder.

Comment: [This](http://www.viking-direct.co.uk/catalog/catalogSku.do?id=5809662) is a ring binder, [this](http://www.bindingstore.co.uk/binding-supplies/wire-binding-supplies/a4-2-1-wire-binding-element/) is a spiral binder. Could you clarify which you mean?

Comment: It is more of the second type; however, it is small (notebook size), but one can open it and change sheets.

Answer (score 2):

Consider calling them ***refillable*** spiral binders. Here are some examples, though please note that the links are to commercial offerings of that description (emphasis, mine):

- POST **Refillable** Spiral Notebook
  [- Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004X9ZF04)
- Makers of **Refillable** Books // How to Add and Remove Pages
  [- Komtrack](http://www.komtrak.com/)

> **refill** *transitive verb*: to fill again : replenish;
>   *intransitive verb*: to become filled again;
>   **refillable** *adjective*
>   [- M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/refillable)

With *refillable* notebooks, the meaning of *refill* is stretched to include the notion of *adding to* existing pages / leaves, not just replenishing *emptied* notebooks.

Comment: I think this is a suitable suggestion. I shall still pay attention to possible others but want to thank you!